# First question workflow - Does Stack Exchange need a 'question needs more detail' canned response?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, new-users

When I look at the *First Questions queue* I often encounter questions that make perfect sense, so the 'question is unclear' response isn't really appropriate. What the question needs isn't clarity but detail.  An example from Blender SE today was a question that asked, paraphrased: *"why does my mesh disappear."* I end up marking such questions as unclear, then hunting them down in the questions queue and adding another comment asking for more detail.

I also find that new users don't know what to do with 'unclear' and get frustrated when they think the question is clear but haven't realized that they need to add detail before it can be answered.

For workflow purposes, I think it would be useful to have another option 'question needs more detail'; especially if it comes with the ability to specify what detail is missing.

Comment: That close reason already exists: It used to literally be "unclear ..." but sadly changed to "Needs details or clarity" more than a year ago.

Comment: IIRC that works for close, but no as part of First Question?

Comment: Still does not change the fact, we used to have an "unclear" reason, and it was changed to "Needs details or clarity". If the question needs details then "Needs details or clarity" must apply, since "needs details", is in the close reason. So I would argue "Needs details or clarity" applies in both examples you provided.  "Too broad" was changed to "Needs more focus" by the way.

Comment: The thing I'm asking for in the workflow request, I now realize, would also be useful in the close 'Needs details or clarity', because new users are typically not going to know what sort of detail or clarity are needed.  IMO, asking them for specifics is more likely to help them create a good question.

Comment: @MartyFouts "then hunting them down in the question queue " you can simplify this a bit by right clicking on the question title, then select "open in new tab". This way all the questions are already open when you finish your go at the review queue.

Comment: @MartyFouts - How exactly are new users reviewing posts, new users, don't typically have enough reputation to do that.

Comment: They're not.  My comments about new users are meant to be about how they respond to seeing the 'unclear' messages when someone reviews their question or votes to close it.  I'm trying to suggest that it would be more encouraging to new users, and easier for reviewers, if instead of a canned 'unclear' message, an 'needs details' message were available to the reviewer -- one that allows the review as part of the workflow to explain what detail is missing.  This may only apply to technical communities like Blender but it would make a huge difference there.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz There are several different work arounds, but having the option in the workflow means less work for a reviewer and reminds and encourages reviewers to explain why they find the question unclear.  This, in turn, makes it easier for new users to fix their questions, rather than giving up in frustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not exactly what I suggested, the workflow has been changed to offer a 'comment under your own username' option on some review queues, which solves my problem, at least for those review queues.  I consider that an answer to this question.